# uWSGI sometimes stuck and send 502 error

Tags: django, uwsgi

Hello i am using no config file, just use `systemd` with next command to run uwsgi and very simple config `--socket /var/uwgi/uwsgi.socket --module boost.wsgi_django --chmod-socket=666 -p 64`

And sometimes i receive 502 like uwsgi is down but all is ok and no errors even log. It look like server is down for a half of a second and then all is ok again.